# How update data in all row at the same time using ColdFusion

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion

I want to ask how to update data in all row at the same time. This is my SQL:

```
<cfloop index="#form.ppp_id#">
    <cfquery name="viewPoint" datasource="#application.DataSource#">
        update PCRS_PHOTOPOINT set PPP_POINT_FROM = #form.point_from#, 
        PPP_POINT_UNTIL = #form.point_until#,
        PPP_UPDATE_DATE = SYSDATE, PPP_ICONS_NAME = '#form.icons_name#' 
        where PPP_ID = #form.ppp_id#
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

I got this error:

> Attribute validation error for tag 'CFLOOP'

Comment: That error is caused by a different issue, the code posted does not have the cfloop tag.  Somewhere along the way there is a a cfloop tag that is not closed most likely.  Also, you should be using cfqueryparam tags for those variables.

Comment: <cfloop index="#viewPoint.ppp_id#">
 <cfquery name="viewPoint" datasource="#application.DataSource#">
  update PCRS_PHOTOPOINT set PPP_POINT_FROM = #form.point_from#, 
        PPP_POINT_UNTIL = #form.point_until#,
     PPP_UPDATE_DATE = SYSDATE, PPP_ICONS_NAME = '#form.icons_name#' 
        where PPP_ID = #form.ppp_id#
     </cfquery>
  </cfloop>

Comment: The cfloop tag requires more than just the index attribute.  If is is a list, then I would go with <cfloop list="#viewPoint.ppp_id#" index="index">.  Then use the variable #index# in place of #form.ppp_id#.

Comment: <cfloop list="#viewPoint.ppp_id#" index="index">
 <cfquery name="viewPoint" datasource="#application.DataSource#">
  update PCRS_PHOTOPOINT set PPP_POINT_FROM = #form.point_from#, 
        PPP_POINT_UNTIL = #form.point_until#,
     PPP_UPDATE_DATE = SYSDATE, PPP_ICONS_NAME = '#form.icons_name#' 
        where PPP_ID = #index#
     </cfquery>
  </cfloop> I still got this error 'ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification '

Comment: I want to update all the data not to list the data

Comment: That is not what the list attribute is.  The list attribute is saying that your variable viewPoint.ppp_id is a string that is a delimited list of content, i.e. "1,3,6,10", and on each iteration of the loop, a variable by the name of the index attribute will be set to the current item in the list, i.e. first pass: "1", second pass: "2".

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a loop at all. You can use SQL's `in` operator instead of `=` to update a list of values all at once, instead of executing a SQL statement in a loop. Also, as someone else already mentioned, you'd better be using `cfqueryparam` instead of passing user-supplied strings straight to the DB.

```
<cfquery name="viewPoint" datasource="#application.DataSource#">
  update PCRS_PHOTOPOINT set
    PPP_POINT_FROM = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.point_from#">,
    PPP_POINT_UNTIL = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.point_until#">,
    PPP_UPDATE_DATE = SYSDATE,
    PPP_ICONS_NAME = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.icons_name#">
  where PPP_ID in (<cfqueryparam list="yes" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.ppp_id#">)
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing it like this:

```
<cfloop list="#form.ppp_id#" index="iItems">
    <cfquery name="viewPoint" datasource="#application.DataSource#">
        update PCRS_PHOTOPOINT set PPP_POINT_FROM = "#form.point_from#", 
        PPP_POINT_UNTIL = "#form.point_until#",
        PPP_UPDATE_DATE = SYSDATE, PPP_ICONS_NAME = "#form.icons_name#" 
        where PPP_ID = #iItems#
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: use cfqueryparam on those values!! http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html